# custom search against custom post type

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress site i need two types of search one for basic wordpress search another is custom search.both r separate .first one is ok but second one is creating problem.In custom search i have to search category and key word,Here category is custom_taxonomy and post type also custom post type.
taxonomy=faq-group
post_type=faq-item

example: if any one search category=Australia and keyword=visa  Then it will show all post that have visa keyword and Australia category from faq module.
I've searched it in google.I think,i've write custom query
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for achieve this

```
function custom_search_where( $where )
{
    if(isset($_POST['your-custom-serchtext'])){
        $where = "post_content Like %$_POST['your-custom-serchtext']% ", $where );

    }
    return $where;
}

  $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'faq-item','tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'faq-group',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'australia '
        )
    )) );
  add_filter('posts_where', 'custom_search_where' );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'custom_search_where' );
```

I have not tested this code but I hope it will useful for you.

Comment: There is a syntax error in this line $where = "post_content Like %$_POST['your-custom-serchtext']% ", $where );